# Wildcard types, type erasure and runtime signature: what happens on <T extends A & B> where A and B inherit a common ancestor?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, method-signature

(edit: fixed after comments)

Let us take a class or interface `A` and an interface `B` where both inherit a common ancestor `X` (assuming `X` is not `Object`). Let us have a method whose signature is:

```
<T extends A & B> void foo(final T arg)
```

What is the signature of `foo` at runtime? Is that `void foo(X)` or `void foo(Object)`, and the JVM casts to `X` at runtime?

Comment: If A and B are both classes, then your method will cause a compiler error.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oops! missed that part.

Comment: Why don't you compile the class, and use javap to look at the generated code?

Comment: @JBNizet Won't work in this specific case. ;-)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis point taken... I have always used interfaces in bounds so I have never noticed this problem. But I'll remember that!

Comment: @chrylis: with the -v option, you get: `arg   Lcom/foo/bounds/A;` which confirms Rohit's answer. If you switch to B & A, you get `arg   Lcom/foo/bounds/B;`

Comment: @JBNizet The code as described won't compile (and the reason why it won't compile is essentially the rationale for the specified type erasure).

Comment: @chrylis nevermind that, I have fixed the question with regards to comments

Comment: It will compile if A and B are interfaces inheriting a common interface C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The erasure of a type parameter is always the erasure of its left-most bound, doesn't matter what other classes are up there in the inheritance hierarchy ([JLS §4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)). So, the method is erased to:

```
void foo(final A)
```

Of course, as noted in comments, if `A` and `B` both are classes, that code will not compile. The type parameter bounds can not have multiple classes as bounds, but only a single class followed by any number of interfaces.

See [JLS §4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) for the syntax of type variable declaration:

```
TypeParameter:
    TypeVariable TypeBoundopt

TypeBound:
    extends TypeVariable
    extends ClassOrInterfaceType AdditionalBoundListopt

AdditionalBoundList:
    AdditionalBound AdditionalBoundList
    AdditionalBound

AdditionalBound:
    & InterfaceType
```

Any *AdditionalBound* should always be an *InterfaceType*.

> the JVM casts to X at runtime?

Yes the compiler will add appropriate cast so that the code works as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! And this also explains the signature of `Collections.max()` then, where the first bound is `Object` instead of `Comparable`...

Comment: that always to leftmost is quite confusing... `<T extends AutoCloseable & Serializable> void whatType(T... args) {
        System.out.println(args.getClass().getComponentType().getSimpleName());
    }` test this